Poetry package configuration for a project with subpackages
I have a project with two components: api_server and calculator. I want them to be subpackages of the main package grzes_toolkit. This is the repository structure:
grzes_toolkit
├── api_server
│   ├── protos
│   │   └── messages.proto
│   └── python
│       ├── api_server
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── server.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── calculator
│   ├── native
│   │   └── calculator.cc
│   └── python
│       ├── calculator
│       │   ├── arithmetic.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── scientific.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── pyproject.toml

This is the contents of the pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry]
name = "grzes_toolkit"
version = "0.0.5"
description = "A toolkit consisting of an API server and a calculator."
authors = ["grzes314 <email@address.com>"]
packages = [
  { include = "calculator", from = "calculator/python", to = "grzes_toolkit"},
  { include = "api_server", from = "api_server/python", to = "grzes_toolkit" },
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
grpcio = { version = "^1.0", optional=true }
numpy = { version = "^1.20", optional=true }


[tool.poetry.extras]
api_server = ["grpcio"]
calculator = ["numpy"]
all = ["grpcio", "numpy"]

I can use poetry to build a wheel.
$ poetry install
$ poetry build 
Building grzes_toolkit (0.0.5)
  - Building sdist
  - Built grzes_toolkit-0.0.5.tar.gz
  - Building wheel
  - Built grzes_toolkit-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl
$ unzip -l dist/grzes_toolkit-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl 
Archive:  dist/grzes_toolkit-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  1980-01-01 00:00   grzes_toolkit/api_server/__init__.py
       71  1980-01-01 00:00   grzes_toolkit/api_server/server.py
        0  1980-01-01 00:00   grzes_toolkit/calculator/__init__.py
       33  1980-01-01 00:00   grzes_toolkit/calculator/arithmetic.py
        0  1980-01-01 00:00   grzes_toolkit/calculator/scientific.py
      629  1980-01-01 00:00   grzes_toolkit-0.0.5.dist-info/METADATA
       88  1980-01-01 00:00   grzes_toolkit-0.0.5.dist-info/WHEEL
      677  2016-01-01 00:00   grzes_toolkit-0.0.5.dist-info/RECORD
---------                     -------
     1498                     8 files

When I install my wheel in an independent virtual env it looks like I successfully packaged my project:
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install grzes_toolkit-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl[all]
Processing ./grzes_toolkit-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (from grzes-toolkit==0.0.5)
Collecting grpcio<2.0,>=1.0 (from grzes-toolkit==0.0.5->grzes-toolkit==0.0.5)
  Downloading grpcio-1.66.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.20 (from grzes-toolkit==0.0.5->grzes-toolkit==0.0.5)
  Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
Downloading grpcio-1.66.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (5.7 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.7/5.7 MB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (18.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy, grzes-toolkit, grpcio
Successfully installed grpcio-1.66.1 grzes-toolkit-0.0.5 numpy-1.26.4

$ python -c "import grzes_toolkit"
$ python -c "from grzes_toolkit.calculator.arithmetic import add; print(add(4,5))"
9
$ python -c "from grzes_toolkit.api_server.server import get_intro_string; print(get_intro_string())"
I am grzes_toolkit server

However, it seems that the project is not properly installed in my poetry environment:
$ poetry shell
Spawning shell within /home/glos/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/grzes-toolkit-dd-OeUsJ-py3.10
$ pip list
Package       Version Editable project location
------------- ------- ----------------------------
grzes_toolkit 0.0.5   /home/glos/dev/grzes_toolkit
pip           24.1
setuptools    70.1.1
$ python -c "import grzes_toolkit"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grzes_toolkit'

This makes development really cumbersome. Building a wheel everytime I want to check a small change in the code is a lot of hassle. Also, without proper installation of the package (in editable mode!) I will not be able to make IDE recognize imports correctly.
Is this a bug in poetry? Is something wrong in the configuration (pyproject.toml, etc.)?
I'm striving to have to relatively independent components in one wheel. But maybe this whole approach is wrong and I should prepare separate pyproject.toml for each component and build separate wheels? In this case, would it be possible to have them both imported like this:
import grzes_toolkit.api_server
import grzes_toolkit.calculator


I believe it is not a bug but a it is a technical limitation of Poetry. In your development environment Poetry does a so-called "editable" installation. Editable installations allow modifying the Python code without need for reinstall after each change. But my assumption is that editable installations do not work well with the rewrite of the directory tree that your project has (i.e. the from = "calculator/python", to = "grzes_toolkit" part of your project configuration). I have not checked but I would be quite surprised if Poetry is able to handle editable installation for such a project.
